# Can not start apache server

Tags: apache-2.4

I upgraded my server OS from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04. But now I can not start my apache server.

My Command:

```
solutionglobe:/home/solutionglobe/public_html# service apache2 restart
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
 * Restarting web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using solutionglobe.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   ...fail!
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Apache error log:

```
[Fri Oct 24 07:52:48.256697 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 24541] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Fri Oct 24 07:52:48.272414 2014] [fcgid:emerg] [pid 24542] (2)No such file or directory: mod_fcgid: Can't create shared memory for size 1200712 bytes
```

I am using Virtualmin

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Administration panels are off-topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 3):

It seems FCGID's temp directory is missing in your system therefore it can't create a process table file.

Check `fcgid.conf` file. Probably it is here `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf`
Look at `FcgidIPCDir` value. In my case:

```
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
```

Then verify the `/var/run/mod_fcgid` folder exists. Create it if not.

Comment: This works, but next time you reboot the server the directory gets erased and you have the same issue again ([see here](https://serverfault.com/q/779634/189712)).